# OptimisticLockException in pessimistic locking

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am using Spring with Hibernate. I am running jUnit test like this:

```
String number = invoiceNumberService.nextInvoiceNumber();
```

and invoiceNumberService method is:

```
InvoiceNumber invoiceNumber = invoiceNumberRepository.findOne(1L);
```

it is using simple spring data repository method, and it's working well. But when I override this method to use locking:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
@Override
InvoiceNumber findOne(Long id);
```

I am getting "javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction"

I can't understand why its optimistic lock exception, while I am using pessimistic locking? And where is this part when another transaction is changing this entity?
I have already dig a lot similar questions and I am quite desperate about this. Thanks for any help


**Solution:**

The problem was in my init function in test class:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    InvoiceNumber invoiceNumber = new InvoiceNumber(1);
    em.persist(invoiceNumber);
    em.flush();
}
```

There was lack of

```
em.flush();
```

Which saves the data into database, so findOne() can now retreive it

Comment: I ran into the same problem and the same solution. Sounds like a bug to me that Hibernate does not flush by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Have you given the @transcational annotation in dao or service layer?
it happens due to the reason that two transaction is simultaneously trying to change the data of same table..So if you remove all the annotation from the dao layer and put in the service layer it should solve the problem i this..because i faced similar kind of problem.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you read the question from top to bottom? OP mistakenly posted the answer in the question itself instead of as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of it I'll post the following, if any one disagrees please correct me. In general in java you are advised to use Spring/hibernate and JPA. Hibernate implements JPA so you will need dependencies for Spring and Hibernate.

Next let Spring/hibernate manage your transactions and the committing part. It is bad practice to flush/commit your data yourself.

For instance let assume the following method:

```
public void changeName(long id, String newName) {
   CustomEntity entity = dao.find(id);
   entity.setName(newName);
}
```

Nothing will happen after this method (you could call merge and commit). But if you annotate it with @Transactional, your entity will be managed and at the end of the @Transactional method Spring/hibernate will commit your changes. So this is enough:

```
@Transactional
public void changeName(long id, String newName) {
   CustomEntity entity = dao.find(id);
   entity.setName(newName);
}
```

No need to call flush, Spring/Hibernate will handle all the mess for you. Just don't forget that your tests have to call @Transactional methods, or should be @Transactional themselves.